# simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : String not closed expecting problem

Tags: php

```
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : String not closed expecting " or ' in /tmp/x/x.php on line 4
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO 8859-9"?> in /tmp/x/x.php on line 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO 8859-9"?>
```

xml encoding should be as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?>
```